# GKE in cluster load balancing between 2 backend applications

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

I have 2 applications running on my cluster : G and C. G is only one pod and C is on 2 pods.

G is exposed to external connection and C is not. G first receive requests that he then process and sends to C.

So I was wondering how can I load balance the requests that G sends to C between the 2 pods of C.

I am currently using Kubernetes native service for C but I'm not sure if it is load balancing between my 2 pods. Everything I'm reading seems to expose the service externally and I don't want that

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Kubernetes Service of type [ClusterIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) for application C's Deployment. Such Service gets an internal IP which isn't exposed outside of the cluster. The Service does a simple round-robin routing of the traffic among the pods it targets (from the Deployment).

Use this to reference application C from G via the Service:

```
<k8s-service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

The above assumes that there's [DNS](https://v1-13.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) running on the cluster (there usually is).